# Solving ConcurrentModificationException problem with Asynctask (ANDROID)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I get a ConcurrentModificationException (ArrayList) Exception and I am not sure how to solve it, because in the exception comes very rare and is not reproducable.

Situation:
I have a main Thread with:

```
for(Element element : myList){
    Value value = element.getValue(); <-------- ConcurrentModificationException (ArrayList)
}
```

And an AsyncTask with:

```
public class LoadMapObjectsTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // some other logic
        myList.remove(element);
    }
}
```

I can understand the Conflict, but I am not sure how to prevent it correctly. Maybe with simple synchronize{} ? How can I solve this ?

Comment: Is `doSomthing()` running synchronously?

Comment: yes. Its simple executing stuff without any additional thread. I modified the code sample to the real situation.

Comment: I would suggest for you to use a "helper List" so that you are not removing items from a list that is being iterated.

Comment: Or maybe use an Iterator List

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can change the code to return specific value that can be recognized as a sign to remove element using `Iterator.remove()`:

```
Iterator<Element> it = myList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  Value value = it.next().getValue()
  if (value == null) {
    it.remove();
  }
}
```